# jQuery scrollTop transition over time

Tags: jquery

I have a little jQuery script to change my navbar's opacity when someone scrolls to a certain point. However, the transition is instant and I'd like for it to fade. Is this possible?

```
        $(window).scroll(function() {    
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (scroll >= 140) {
                $(".navbar-inverse").css({
                "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,1.0)",
                });
                } else {
                $(".navbar-inverse").css({"background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"});
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fadeTo()`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    $('.navbar-inverse').fadeTo(200, $(window).scrollTop() >= 140 ? 1.0 : 0.4);
});
```

The `200` is the duration of the transition in `ms`, so you can speed up or slow down as needed.

Comment: This is really close to what I need. Except I need it to go from lighter color to 100% opaque (dark). I tried switching the values and it didn't work.

Also, this makes all of the contents inside the div fade as well.

And, if possible, I need to set it so it returns to the original value when the window is scrolled back to the top.